# How to calculate a number and turn it into vw or vh?

Tags: javascript, css, viewport, viewport-units

I am relatively new to programming and I've run into a problem.
I want to calculate a number and turn it into a viewport unit.

The calculation I am trying to do is 100 / height * width and the number that comes out of this equation should be in a viewport unit. Width and height are pre-defined variables in my code I have tried putting the equation in all types of brackets, I have tried putting the viewport unit inside of the equation like this: 100vw / width = height. But everything gives me an error.

The full part:

```
if (h / height > w / width) {
   container.style.width = [100 / width * height]vw;
   container.style.height = 100vw;
}
```

```
container.style.width = [100 / width * height]vw;
```

and

```
container.style.width = 100vw / width * height;
```

Please let me know if this is possible in javascript. I am not familiar with jquery so jquery answers won't help me. I am open to learning how to calculate something like this in css, but I don't know how I would implement an if statement than. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `width` and `height` variables contain numbers, do the math first, then append the string "vw":

```
container.style.width = (100 / width * height) + "vw"
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the right syntax works for what you want to achieve.

```
if (h / height > w / width) {
   container.style.width = (100 / width * height) + 'vw';
   container.style.height = '100vw';
}
```

If you could provide more info as to how you determine 'pre-defined variables' of vw and vh.

And if you are trying to find which is bigger/smaller, you could use vmin and vmax directly.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is treated as a string in JavaScript, so you must have quotations for it to work. In both your `container.style.width` and `container.style.height` you need to make the values strings. There are 2 ways you can do this.

First, you can keep it the way you have it, but turn it into a calculation + a string:

```
if (h / height > w / width) {
    container.style.width = (100 / width * height) + "vw";
    container.style.height = "100vw";
}
```

or you can create a variable and append the string after:

```
if (h / height > w / width) {
    var width = (100 / width * height);
    container.style.width = width + "vw";
    container.style.height = "100vw";
}
```